# объясните код STL

Tags: c++, stl

Очень прошу объяснить данный код. Что конкретно делают функции `for_each` и `for` (по возможности объяснить построчно что происходит)

`main.cpp`

```
int main() {
    map<string, set<string>> m1, m2, m3;
    m1 = {
        {"Ukraine", {"Kharkiv", "Kiev"}},
        {"Russia", {"Moscow", "Belgorod"}},
        {"Belarus", {"Minsk", "Bobruysk"}}
    };

    m2 = {
        {"Poland", {"Warsaw"}},
        {"Russia", {"Saint-Petersburg"}},
        {"Ukraine", {"Kharkiv", "Zaporizhya"}}
    };

    m3 = m1;

    for_each(m2.begin(), m2.end(), [&](const pair<string, set<string>> & pair) {
        auto it = m3.find(pair.first);
        if (it == m3.end())
            m3.insert(pair);
        else
            it->second.insert(pair.second.begin(), pair.second.end());
    });

    for (map<string, set<string>> *m : array<map<string, set<string>>*, 3>{&m1, &m2, &m3}) {
        cout << endl;
        for (pair<string, set<string>> k : *m) {
            cout << k.first << ": ";
            for (string s : k.second)
                cout << s << ", ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Прям каждая строчка непонятна или что-то конкретное?

Comment: Непонятны строчки:
for_each (строка)
for (полностью)

Comment: `cout << s << ", ";` выводит `s` и `", "` в стандартный поток вывода

Comment: Я не понимаю вопросы, где просят объяснять код. Если вам не хватает знаний для понимания кода, что вам даст чье то объяснение?  Не лучше ли просто изучать и пользоваться тем, что уже изучено?...

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не смог это найти в интернете, либо не смог понять. Однако я стремлюсь к пониманию, поэтому и спрашиваю. Я понял что мне написали.

Comment: @Lcashe ладно лямбду, но "for_each c++" можно легко в поисковике забить же

Comment: @dIm0n я знаю что такое for_each, я не понял содержимое, а конкретно вот это: [&](const pair<string, set<string>> & pair)

Comment: @Lcashe почему вы сразу это не сказали? Я же спросил *"или что-то конкретное?"*, на что вы ответили *"for_each (строка) for (полностью)"*

Comment: вы просто не поняли меня. (строка) я имел ввиду вся строка с for_each

Comment: @Lcashe в общем, при наборе "for_each c++" вы попадаете на https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each, где рассказано, что означает 3 параметр, более того, в примере как раз используется лямбда

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::for_each` - это функция из [библиотеки алгоритмов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Её смысл - пройтись по всем элементам контейнера(массиву, например) и применить к каждому элементу [функтор](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object)

В данном случае в качестве контейнера выступает `std::map`([ассоциативный массив](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)), а функтором - [лямбда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)(безымянная функция)

Смысл этого участка кода - слияние(`merge`) двух `std::map` в третий

Сейчас этот `std::for_each` можно заменить на [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) - цикл `for` по контейнеру.

`range-for` как раз применен во втором непонятном для Вас участке кода.

`range-for` как и `std::for_each` пробегается по всем элементам контейнера и выполняет какие то действия.

В данном случае происходит вывод на печать для каждого элемента из списка `{&m1, &m2, &m3}`

Comment: спасибо большое. а что такое [&]?

Comment: @Lcashe, захват всех локальных переменных по ссылке.

Comment: std::for_each всегда можно было заменять циклом(как и все стандартные алгоритмы), но в некоторых случаях(не в этом коде),  его использование удобнее, с учетом того, что алгоритм возвращает применяемый функтор, где может быть сохранена важная информация...

Comment: @Lcashe, `[&]` относится к lambda: в квадратных скобках указывается список захвата. В квадратных скобках указывается какие переменные и каким образом пробрасываются в область видимости lambda.